# How to get the style value using attr

Tags: jquery, html, css, attr

My HTML CODE HERE:

```
 <i id="bgcolor" style="background-color: rgb(255, 146, 180)"></i>
```

I want to get the background-color value using jquery attr. What i tried is below:

```
$("#bgcolor").mouseleave(function(){
        var bodyColor = $(this).attr("style");

        $("body").css(bodyColor);
    });
```

But this output is:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 146, 180);
```

And now that I've added it to my css it will not work. How can I achieve this task?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to fetch styles with `attr()` instead of `css()`?

Comment: refer http://api.jquery.com/css/ .You will get the solution there :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check out the documentation for .css: http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
var bodyColor = $(this).css("backgroundColor");
```

Comment: am i mistaken, or isn't it `background-color`?

Comment: @Andreas: [it doesn't matter](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SLFnf/), they're both valid/equivalent under jQuery.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair It's either, from the documentation: "Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css({'background-color': '#ffe', 'border-left': '5px solid #ccc'}) and .css({backgroundColor: '#ffe', borderLeft: '5px solid #ccc'}). Notice that with the DOM notation, quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name."

Comment: This is the answer what i want.Thanks @dwaddell.

Comment: is there any better event that i can use with the colorpicker instead of mouseleave ?

Comment: @DiliniWasana That's a whole different question and it depends on what you are trying to do, click, mousedown, mouseleave, etc. could be appropriate.

Comment: I'm going to change body background color when user tick the color from the data picker

Answer (score 5):

This is what you are looking for(this code works):

```
$("#bgcolor").mouseleave(function(){
    var bodyColor = $(this).attr("style");
    $("body").attr("style", bodyColor);
});
```

But, instead of using `attr` you should use `css`, so the code will be:

```
$("#bgcolor").mouseleave(function(){
    var bodyColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $("body").css("background-color", bodyColor);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq9Xz/)

Comment: is there any better event that i use with the colorpicker instead of mouseleave ?

Comment: @Zenith, lol. Dilini, it depends on what you need to do. What do you need it for?

Comment: @DiliniWasana : you can jquery colorpicker plugin. http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do the trick, replace your

```
$("body").css(bodyColor);
```

With

```
$("body").attr('style', $(this).attr("style"));
```

That should change the style to whatever the style on the other object is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$("#bgcolor").css("backgroundColor");` to obtain the colour.

Comment: is there any better event that i use with the colorpicker instead of mouseleave ?

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dV53b/)

```
$("#bgcolor").mouseleave(function(){
    var bodyColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $("body").css("background-color",bodyColor);
});
```