# JQuery problem turning HTML element 'visibility' property on and off

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Am trying to create a button that when clicked, shows the table with id 'compose1' and when the button is clicked again, the table collapses and is invisible.

The code works fine on first click, and shows the table, but won't work on second click. The table won't collapse back on second click.

I know the issue is somewhere at the code

```
var msgAttr= $(`#compose${msgid}`).style.visibility
```

because it gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visibility')`.

Could you help me spot where the issue is?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" onclick="composeMsg('1'); return false;" title="Button"> Click Button </a>


<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="compose1" style="visibility: collapse;">
<tr>
<td align="bottom" valign="bottom">
My Table
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
    function composeMsg(msgid) {  

        var msgAttr= $(`#compose${msgid}`).style.visibility; 
        //var msgAttr = 'hidden';
        
        if(msgAttr=='hidden'){
          $(`#compose${msgid}`).attr("style","visibility: visible;"); 
        } else {
          $(`#compose${msgid}`).attr("style","visibility: collapse;"); 
        }

    }  
</script>
```

Comment: Using jQuery ( `$("something")` ) gives you a jQuery object, **not** a DOM element reference. You have to use the jQuery API to manipulate the elements.

Comment: Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549137/how-to-get-the-style-value-using-attr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the style value using attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549137/how-to-get-the-style-value-using-attr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing *jQuery* and vanilla *JavaScript* syntax. *jQuery* doesn't work directly with the `style` *property* in the same way as vanilla *JavaScript* does. You should use *jQuery*'s methods to manipulate CSS properties.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" onclick="composeMsg('1'); return false;" title="Button"> Click Button </a>

<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="compose1" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td align="bottom" valign="bottom">
            My Table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
function composeMsg(msgid) {
    var msgElement = $(`#compose${msgid}`);
    if (msgElement.css('display') === 'none') {
        msgElement.css('display', 'table'); //show the table
    } else {
        msgElement.css('display', 'none'); //hide the table
    }
}
</script>
```